# Explicitly set WPF binding datatype

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, types

I wanted to ask if WPF has any functionality by which one can define a target type on a `binding` when the binding is done to an object of type "`object`".  I have a generic collection of type "`object`" that must be handled as one object type or the other (ie. `DateTime`, `int`, etc.) at its various binding points.

Is there any way that I can arbitrarily force the .Net framework to treat objects of unknown type at compile time as objects of `Type_X`, on a case-by-case basis when handling bindings?

Comment: You could make a converter that returns a value based on the type of the value passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) class doesn't provide any such feature; Actually it doesn't need to, Binding framework automatically converts the source object to relevant type and uses the bound property  value, or else raises a binding error if that property is not found.

So if I have a property of `Object` type in my `ViewModel`

```
public object Dummy 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return dummy; 
    } 
    set 
    { 
        dummy = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Dummy");
    } 
}
```

and I bound it to a `TextBox` like this -

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Dummy.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

and later set the Dummy to an object like this -

```
Dummy = new MyCustomType();
```

at this point binding will evaluate and try to find the `Name` property in the source object(`Dummy`) and if `MyCustomType` defines a public property named `Name` then binding will execute else a binding error will occur( no exception just an error msg. in output window).

Now, in case I want to set my `Dummy` property to objects of two different types(one having `Name` and other having `FirstName`) then I have two options -

1. Define `DataTemplates` as Botz300 suggested
2. Use a `ValueConverter` (which checks the object type and returns relevant property value).

Another variant of using `ValueConverter` is defining a [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(VS.80).aspx) to do conversion and declare it with the [`TypeConverterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute(v=VS.80).aspx), then in bindings automatic conversion will be done.

Same applies for collection of objects.

**Update:**

Yes, WPF will implicitly use `DefaultType` converter to convert your type to relevant display value. In case you bind the `Object` directly to a property(`Text` in above example) then WPF will use the `TypeConverter` for that type(if available) or use the `ToString()` method to get the display value.

But all this depend on the control you are using for displaying the data and how/what you are binding.

> Note: This trick only suffices for objects that can have simple
>   textual representations. It might not make sense to use this
>   convenient technique when dealing with complex data objects.
>
> You can go through this article on MSDN which talks about this -
>   [Customize Data Display with Data Binding and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx)

Comment: Your answer sounds very good, seems like you've understood my problem. In my case, the object type property can only hold "primitive" types, like integers, dates, etc. Now I just want the binding framework to behave like the property was of the specific type.

Gues that's what you meant with the ValueConverter. Can you pass me any sample for this? Is it possible to use the "default" Converter, that binding framework seems to use? Or do I really have to write my own, new converter?

Comment: Binding does need to do that. For example, `ToolTip="{Binding Price,StringFormat=c}"`: `StringFormat` is *silently* ignored because `ToolTip` is of type Object. Nothing in the debug output. I am aware that "silent failure for non-obvious reasons whenever possible" is one of the key design goals of XAML, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea. Yes, there are several ways to work around this specific problem with StringFormat. There always are.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you can use [`DataTemplates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx). If you define them in your App.xaml, they will be applied globally:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:YourType}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now whenever you add an object of runtime type `YourType` somewhere in your UI, like in a `StackPanel`, that Template will be used.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to find a way to make a binding to a property of unspecific type "object" behave like it is a DateTime-type, for example.

Comment: @user1039407 So you have an object of runtime type `object` and want it to behave like datetime? where would you get the actual DateTime data from?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can specify the type in the `Path` property of the binding by surrounding the property name with parenthesis and adding `<Type>.` in front.

Example:

```
<ContextMenu Tag="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.(FrameworkElement.Tag), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
...
</ContextMenu>
```

This specifies that the property `Tag` is a member of the `FrameworkElement` type and is indicating that `PlacementTarget` is of that type.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can set a designtime DataContext with d:DataContext - if you only want your IDE to know what kind of data it has to expect.

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}"
             DataContext="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource BindingProxy}}"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance tree:DesktopViewModel}">
    [items...]
</ContextMenu>
```

I have a ContextMenu which gets it's DataContext from a BindingProxy (which has a Data-Property of type object). For VS and Resharper to work correctly, they have to know the type of the DataContext, so i simply define a designtime DataContext and now they know it's a `DesktopViewModel`.

This only works with the DataContext, not with any binding (because there's no such thing as DesignTimeBinding), but maybe you can rewrite your bindings to refer to that DataContext (or wrap your controls in a grid which has the DataContext and d:DataContext).