# ListBox DataTemplate for dynamically loaded type

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a sample MVVM WPF application and I'm having problems creating DataTemplates for my dynamically loaded model. Let me try explain:

I have the following simplified classes as part of my Model, which I'm loading dynamically

```
public class Relationship
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public ParticipantsType Participants { get; set; }
}

public class ParticipantsType
{
    public ObservableCollection<ParticipantType> Participant { get; set; }
}

public class ParticipantType
{

}

public class EmployeeParticipant : ParticipantType
{
    public EmployeeIdentityType Employee { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentParticipant : ParticipantType
{
    public DepartmentIdentityType Department { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeIdentityType
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentIdentityType
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how my View Model looks like. I created a generic object `Model` property to expose my Model:

```
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase<MainViewModel>
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SetMockModel();
    }

    private void SetMockModel()
    {
        Relationship rel = new Relationship();
        rel.Category = "213";
        EmployeeParticipant emp = new EmployeeParticipant();
        emp.Employee = new EmployeeIdentityType();
        emp.Employee.ID = "222";
        DepartmentParticipant dep = new DepartmentParticipant();            
        dep.Department = new DepartmentIdentityType();
        dep.Department.ID = "444";
        rel.Participants = new ParticipantsType() { Participant = new ObservableCollection<ParticipantType>() };
        rel.Participants.Participant.Add(emp);
        rel.Participants.Participant.Add(dep);            
        Model = rel;
    }

    private object _Model;
    public object Model
    {
        get { return _Model; }
        set
        {
            _Model = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.Model);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried creating a ListBox to display specifically the Participants Collection:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Model.Participants.Participant}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Expander Header="IdentityFields">
            <!-- WHAT TO PUT HERE IF PARTICIPANTS HAVE DIFFERENT PROPERTY NAMES -->
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The problem is:

1. I don't know how to create a template that can handle both type of ParticipantTypes, in this case I could have EmployeeParticipant or DepartmentParticipant so depending on that, the data binding Path would be set to `Employee` or `Department` properties accordingly
2. I though about creating a DataTemplate for each type (e.g. x:Type EmployeeParticipant) but the problem is that my **classes in my model are loaded dynamically at runtime** so VisualStudio will complain that those types don't exist in the current solution.

How could I represent this data in a ListBox then if my concrete types are not known at compile time, but only at runtime?

**EDIT:** Added my test ViewModel class

Comment: Here a Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152401/explicitly-set-wpf-binding-datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still create a `DataTemplate` for each type but instead of using `DataType` declarations to have them automatically resolve you can create a `DataTemplateSelector` with a property for each template (assigned from `StaticResource` in XAML) that can cast the incoming data item to the base class and check properties or otherwise determine which template to use at runtime. Assign that selector to `ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector` and you'll get similar behavior to what `DataType` would give you.

Comment: After evaluating all the different options I think your answer is what better does the job according to my requirements. I am just checking the item object type in my `ItemTemplateSelector` and based on that return a DataTemplate.   I'll update the question with my final approach based on your suggestion. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a good view-model. Your view-model should be view-centric, not business-centric. So make a class that can handle all four cases from a visual perspective, then bridge your business classes over to that view-model.

---

EDIT:

Working off your code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Model.Participants}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Expander Header="IdentityFields">
                <TextBlock Text={Binding Id} />
                <TextBlock Text={Binding Name} />
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I changed the binding, I assume that was a mistake?

I would create a ViewModel for Participant:

```
public class Participant_VM : ViewModelBase
{

    private string _name = string.Empty;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name ;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
        }

    private string _id= string.Empty;
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_id== value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Id);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you brought that up. I added my whole ViewModel class to the question.

Comment: When you say 'make a class that can handle all four cases from a visual perspective' you mean XAML Views @Shlomo?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `ListBox` as follows.

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Model.Participants.Participant}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:DepartmentParticipant}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Department.ID}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type loc:EmployeeParticipant}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Employee.ID}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Expander Header="IdentityFields">
                            <!-- WHAT TO PUT HERE IF PARTICIPANTS HAVE DIFFERENT PROPERTY NAMES -->
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }"/>
                        </Expander>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Edit:
loc refers to the namespace in which the `DepartmentParticipant` and `EmployeeParticipant` are present. Hope you are familiar with adding namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, like I said, my Model types are loaded at runtime so I won't be able to use those types at design time. Even if I add a reference to my model dll in the WPF Project, it adds the namespace: `xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:;assembly=PIM_SBP.TransactionPolicy"` but still doesn't work. I get: 'The type reference cannof find a public type named DepartmentParticipant'